TikZ: Fix dimensions / fontsizes for simple poker playing cards
The typically sizes of a poker-card are 6 x 9 = width x height, so I choose values
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\w{<card width>}% card width
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{9*\w/6}% card height

for a "cardground" rectangle node.
But how to make sure that the texts (e.g. A over $\heartsuit$) fits good inside the card-node? 
Maybe with scale?
In the following MWE I set commands \cardsymbol and \cardcolor which allows a syntax 
\crd{A}{h} or in common \crd{<card value A,1-10,J,Q,K>}{<card color s,h,d,c>}

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% Card-Style =============================
\definecolor{spadecolor}{HTML}{020202}% myblack % spade - Pik
\definecolor{heartcolor}{HTML}{C70002}% myred % heart - Herz
\definecolor{diamondcolor}{HTML}{687CF5}% myblue % diamond - Karo
\definecolor{clubcolor}{HTML}{3B7801}% mygreen % club - Kreuz
\colorlet{cardbackcolor}{purple}% card back
\colorlet{cardplaincolor}{black}% empty card
\colorlet{jokercolor}{violet}% joker
%
\newcommand\cardsymbol[1]{%
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{s}=0 $\spadesuit$%
  \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{h}=0 $\heartsuit$% 
    \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{d}=0 $\diamondsuit$% 
       \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{c}=0 $\clubsuit$% 
\fi\fi\fi\fi}
%
\newcommand\cardcolor[1]{%
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{s}=0 spadecolor%
  \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{h}=0 heartcolor% 
    \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{d}=0 diamondcolor% 
       \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{c}=0 clubcolor% 
\fi\fi\fi\fi}
% ================================

% Card-Sizes (default)=======================
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\w{1.2em}% card width
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{9*\w/6}% card height
% ================================

% \crd[<TikZ adds>]{<card value A,1-10,J,Q,K>}{<card color s,h,d,c>}
\newcommand\crd[3][]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
cardtext/.style={inner sep=0pt, inner ysep=0.045*\h},
cardground/.style={minimum width=\w, minimum height=\h, 
draw, rounded corners=0.075*\w},
]
\node(temp)[cardground, 
label={[cardtext, anchor=north, text=\cardcolor{#3}]north:#2},
label={[cardtext, anchor=south, text=\cardcolor{#3}]south:\cardsymbol{#3}},
 #1]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\section{Let's try the default}
I choose the cards \crd{K}{c}, \crd{A}{h}, \crd{Q}{d}, \crd{7}{s}.

(Dimensions could be better...)

\section{Now a huge card}
% Card-Sizes =============================
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\w{3.1em}% card width
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{9*\w/6}% card height
% ================================
\crd{A}{h} has very much white space :( 
\end{document}



I made the font size depend on card height and increased the inner y sep a bit.
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}% only needed if you are using cm fonts
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% Card-Style =============================
\definecolor{spadecolor}{HTML}{020202}% myblack % spade - Pik
\definecolor{heartcolor}{HTML}{C70002}% myred % heart - Herz
\definecolor{diamondcolor}{HTML}{687CF5}% myblue % diamond - Karo
\definecolor{clubcolor}{HTML}{3B7801}% mygreen % club - Kreuz
\colorlet{cardbackcolor}{purple}% card back
\colorlet{cardplaincolor}{black}% empty card
\colorlet{jokercolor}{violet}% joker
%
\newcommand\cardsymbol[1]{%
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{s}=0 $\spadesuit$%
  \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{h}=0 $\heartsuit$% 
    \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{d}=0 $\diamondsuit$% 
       \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{c}=0 $\clubsuit$% 
\fi\fi\fi\fi}
%
\newcommand\cardcolor[1]{%
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{s}=0 spadecolor%
  \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{h}=0 heartcolor% 
    \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{d}=0 diamondcolor% 
       \else \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{c}=0 clubcolor% 
\fi\fi\fi\fi}
% ================================

% Card-Sizes (default)=======================
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\w{1.2em}% card width
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{9*\w/6}% card height
% ================================

% \crd[<TikZ adds>]{<card value A,1-10,J,Q,K>}{<card color s,h,d,c>}
\newcommand\crd[3][]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\fontsize{.45\dimexpr\h\relax}{.45\dimexpr\h\relax}\sffamily,
cardtext/.style={inner sep=0pt, inner ysep=0.075*\h},
cardground/.style={minimum width=\w, minimum height=\h, 
draw, rounded corners=0.075*\w},
]
\node(temp)[cardground, 
label={[cardtext, anchor=north, text=\cardcolor{#3}]north:#2},
label={[cardtext, anchor=south, text=\cardcolor{#3}]south:\cardsymbol{#3}},
 #1]{};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\section{Let's try the default}
I choose the cards \crd{K}{c}, \crd{A}{h}, \crd{Q}{d}, \crd{7}{s}.

(Dimensions could be better...)

\section{Now a huge card}
% Card-Sizes =============================
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\w{3.1em}% card width
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\h{9*\w/6}% card height
% ================================
\crd{A}{h} has very much white space :( 
\end{document}


Looks good;  especially at \crd{10}{h} (the widest case).
